# Ignoring/Clearing Extra integers from user input

Tags: java, input, integer

I am stuck on this part of a program where the user enters multiple integers and only the first is selected. In my current code, the output is this.

```
There are 10 sticks on the board.
Jerry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? *1 3 4 2*
There are 9 sticks on the board.
Sherry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? There are 6 sticks on the board.
Jerry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? Please enter a number between 1 and 3.
Jerry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? There are 4 sticks on the board.
Sherry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)?
```

While in the given example, the output is this.

```
Jerry: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? *1 3 4 2*
There are 8 sticks on the board.
Pat: How many sticks do you take (1-3)? *3*
There are 5 sticks on the board.
```

It seems that the extra integers are queued up and waiting for the next scanner input command. In the given example, the extra integers are cleared away. How is this being done? Is there a command to clear all current user input or are all of the integers read in with .hasNextInt and any past the first one are simply tossed away? Also, where does hasNextInt look in the input? After resulting true or false, will the next hasNextInt command look in the same input location if no new input has been added?

(The text enclosed by ** is user input.)

Comment: Please include your code in the question.

Comment: Add your code. I'm guessing you use `while(sc.hasNextInt()) {} ` instead of an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't be sure the user will enter the input correctly, you can do it by accepting `String`s instead of `int`s. Like so:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("How many?: ");
int many = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine().trim().split(" ")[0]);
System.out.println(many);
```

This will even handle inputs like `"   2   5 6 5"` as well as the examples you have by taking the entire input string, trimming off any leading and trailing `" "`s, splitting the string into an array of `String`s around `" "`s, and returning the first one (the one you want) at index `0`.

What it doesn't do, as written, is take care of inputs like `" foo bar 42"` or any other inputs where the first index of the split string is not able to be parsed as an integer. Trying to do so will result in a `NumberFormatException`.